# How do I access Session value in an .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

I want to access my session value in .aspx page, I try with so many method but still it doesn't show value.

```
if (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text == "Arabic")
        Session["dir"] = "rtl";
    else
        Session["dir"] = "ltr";
```

**I do like this but can't access session value :**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir='<%# Session["dir"].ToString() %>'  runat="server">
```

Any auggestion really appreciate.

Comment: Where are you setting the session? I mean in which event?

Comment: on button click in Home page & view session value in other pages.

Comment: Are you sure that the session variable is set before the page is rendered? If not the session is empty and it will display nothing or throw an exception.

Comment: Try setting a default value in the Global.asax file in the function Application_Start: `Session["dir"] = "ltr";`

Comment: @DononDex: Can you please let me know it is correct syntax >>      dir='<%# Session["dir"].ToString() %>'

Comment: That should be the correct syntax yes. However add the default session value to the function "Session_Start" inside your Global.asax file

Answer (score 1):

Access it through javascript and set it where you want

[See Here](http://shekharshetemcts.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/how-to-access-session-variables-using-javascript-in-asp-net/)

Comment: He has problems using `<%# Session["dir"].ToString() %>`. Therefor your answer is not related to this problem. And your link suggest to use exact that. His problem is that the session is empty for some reason.